#Gateway Cloning How does gene of interest replace ccdB genes?
I knew that Gateway cloning used a site-specific recombination method, but I still cannot figure out how does gene of interest actually replace ccdB genes? Bacteriophage site-specific recombination
Does the paper explanation somehow clarify what I'm confused about?

Welcome to Biology SE! Thank you for showing your own attempt to answer this question. It would be helpful if you could state that this is a review paper on bacteriophage lambda site-specific recombination, and point to a specific section of the paper or quotation from the paper that you think might contain the answer to your question or that you are confused about.
